# Output dimension of a custom LSTM model in Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

I have a custom LSTM model in PyTorch like below:

```
hidden_size = 32  
num_layers = 1
num_classes = 2

class customModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes):
        super(customModel, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.bilstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
        self.fcl = nn.Linear(hidden_size*2, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Set initial hidden and cell states 
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers*2, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device)
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers*2, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device)

        # Forward propagate LSTM
        out, hidden = self.bilstm(x, (h0, c0)) 
        fw_bilstm = out[-1, :, :self.hidden_size]
        bk_bilstm = out[0, :, :self.hidden_size]
        concat_fw_bw = torch.cat((fw_bilstm, bk_bilstm), dim = 1)
        fc = self.fcl(concat_fw_bw)
        x = F.softmax(F.relu(fc))
        return x
```

I can pass an input of type `torch.Tensor` to this model. The input is of length `67349`, each is a `300` dimension vector.

After model initiation and prediction, I get an output vector of length `1`.

```
model = customModel(300, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes)
output = model(input_torch)
```

The output shows `tensor([[0.5020, 0.4980]], grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward>)` when I print it out.

Why is this output of length `1`? It seems like I should NOT have `barch_first=True` in my model but changing that requires other input dimension changes which I am not sure how to do.

Please suggest how can I get a vector output of length `67349` (input length) instead of `1`?

**Explanation**

I see @gorjan suggested some modifications in the `forward` method of the network. So I wanted to clarify more what I am trying to build

1. Feed the embedding to a BiLSTM (done)
2. Get the hidden states of the last step in each direction and concatenate
3. Fed the concatenated output (from step 2) to a fully connected layer
   with ReLUs
4. Fed the output from step 3 to a softmax layer

Answer (score 0):

I have commented the `def forward(...)` method your module, have a look:

```
def forward(self, x):
    # Set initial hidden and cell states 
    h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers*2, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device)
    c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers*2, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device)

    # Forward propagate LSTM
    out, hidden = self.bilstm(x, (h0, c0)) # out is of size [batch_size, sequence_length, hidden_size * num_directions]
    fw_bilstm = out[-1, :, :self.hidden_size] # This is wrong: You are taking only last batch element
    bk_bilstm = out[0, :, :self.hidden_size] # This is wrong: You are taking only the first batch element
    concat_fw_bw = torch.cat((fw_bilstm, bk_bilstm), dim = 1) # This is not needed: If you want to obtain the hidden states for all elements in the sequence
    fc = self.fcl(concat_fw_bw) # Because of the above mentioned issues, this is wrong as well.
    x = F.softmax(F.relu(fc)) # This is wrong: Never stack activation on top of activation.
    return x
```

Now, according to what you asked:

> Please suggest how can I get a vector output of length 67349 (input length) instead of 1?

I suppose that you want to obtain the hidden states for each of you elements in the batch. Here is how you should structure your forward pass:

```
def forward(self, x):
    # Set initial hidden and cell states 
    h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers*2, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device)
    c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers*2, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device)

    # Forward propagate LSTM
    out, hidden = self.bilstm(x, (h0, c0)) # out is of size [batch_size, sequence_length, hidden_size * num_directions]
    fc = self.fcl(out) # fc is of size [batch_size, sequence_length, num_classes]
    x = F.softmax(fc) # Just softmax so that you can get the probabilities for each of your classes
    return x
```

If we test out the updated model, these are the results:

```
# Assuming 32 elements in the batch, each elements has 177 elements in the sequence, and each sequence element has size 300
inputs = torch.rand(32, 177, 300)
# Obtaining the outputs from the model
outputs = model(inputs)
# The size is as expected: torch.Size([32, 177, 2])
print(outputs.shape)
```

Another thing to keep in mind, you say:

> The input is of length 67349, each is a 300 dimension vector.

This is an extremely long sequence. You model will drastically underperform and I guess that your training would last forever. However, that is a completely different issues and should be discusses in a separate thread.

Comment: please see my explanation

Comment: Can you post the expected input size and the expected output size as well as a clarification of what the size is?